# Finding the web services exposed by a Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that exposes APIs to get content. I have access to the admin console but I don't know how to find the interface / documentation. How do I do that? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to open WP-ADMIN by adding /wp-admin to the end of your WordPress installation's URL and once you're there expand the Settings Panel > Click Writing and scroll down to the section labeled Remote Publishing and note the Atom Publishing Protocol and XML-RPC.

For more info please see the WordPress Codex documentation on [Settings Writing Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Writing_Screen).

Comment: Hi Virgil, isn't that for publishing? How do I read the contents?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question, I'm not understanding what you need.